# MySQL- add Business hour that shop open two times per day after a break

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

The restaurant opens Monday at 10 am till Tuesday 03 am and It opens again on Tuesday at 10 am till Wednesday 03 am.

For example:
table: `business_hour`

```
id | weedDay | openDay | openTime | closeDay | closeTime
-----------------------------------------------------------
1  | Monday  | Monday  | 10:00:00 | Tuesday  | 03:00:00 
2  | Tuesday | Tuesday | 10:00:00 | Wednday  | 03:00:00
```

How to make MySQL SELECT sentence that shows is resturant open or not?

```
<?php 

require_once "pdo/pdo.php";

    try {
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("
            SELECT 
             CASE WHEN
                exists (
                  SELECT 1 FROM business_hour WHERE
                  (openday = dayname(now()) AND opentime <= time(now()))
                  OR
                  (closeday = dayname(now()) AND closetime >= time(now()))               
                )
                THEN 'Open'
                ELSE 'Closed'
              END status
            ");
    $stmt->execute();
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        echo $row['status'];
    }


    } catch( PDOException $e ) {
        echo $e.'Not selected'; // error message
    }    
?>
```

Comment: Your query seems correct. Is it not working as expected? Do you have rows for other days in the table? May be you need to store time in 24 hour format e.g. 15:00 instead of 03:00? is timezone of server machine same as timezone of shop?

Comment: @SameerNaik check new update of the question. I am now getting just open result if I set the old time also. I don’t know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to know if the restaurant is open now:

```
select 
  case when
    exists (
      select 1 from business_hour where
      (openday = dayname(now()) and opentime <= time(now()))
      or
      (closeday = dayname(now()) and closetime >= time(now()))               
    )
    then 'Open'
    else 'Closed'
  end status;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oUJWsEAFTnvqMFa4UUmT6q/0)
This will work only if there are valid day names in the table `business_hour`, 
so typos like `Wednday` instead of `Wednesday` will make it fail.

Comment: could you please check my updated question. I just get open result from status. I don’t know why.

Comment: This is php code. I can't help you with that. My query is sql code for MySql and it works as is.